# After upgrading to 16.10 no wifi connections

Tags: networking, wireless, broadcom, 16.10, connection

I upgraded to Ubuntu 16.10 but since then only Ethernet is working and I can't connect to any WiFi network.

How I can troubleshoot and solve this issue ?

Some info from my laptop:

```
me@my-LAP:~$ iwconfig
wlp3s0b1  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=19 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

eno1      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

me@my-LAP:~$ uname -a
Linux XLAP 4.8.0-32-generic #34-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 13 14:30:43 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

me@my-LAP:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -A3 BCM4313
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [1028:0015]
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
    Kernel modules: bcma
0c:00.0 SD Host controller [0805]: O2 Micro, Inc. OZ600FJ0/OZ900FJ0/OZ600FJS SD/MMC Card Reader Controller [1217:8221] (rev 05)

me@my-LAP:~$  cat /var/log/syslog | grep etwork | tail -n20
Jan  4 08:34:41 XLAP NetworkManager[1037]: <info>  [1483511681.1499] device (wlp3s0b1): Activation: (wifi) access point 'MIR-Link' has security, but secrets are required.
Jan  4 08:34:41 XLAP NetworkManager[1037]: <info>  [1483511681.1499] device (wlp3s0b1): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none') [50 60 0]
Jan  4 08:34:41 XLAP NetworkManager[1037]: <info>  [1483511681.1884] device (wlp3s0b1): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none') [60 40 0]
Jan  4 08:34:41 XLAP NetworkManager[1037]: <info>  [1483511681.1890] device (wlp3s0b1): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Jan  4 08:34:41 XLAP NetworkManager[1037]: <info>  [1483511681.1896] device (wlp3s0b1): Activation: (wifi) connection 'MIR-Link' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Jan  4 08:34:41 XLAP NetworkManager[1037]: <info>  [1483511681.1901] Config: added 'ssid' value 'MIR-Link'
Jan  4 08:34:41 XLAP NetworkManager[1037]: <info>  [1483511681.1913] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Jan  4 08:34:41 XLAP NetworkManager[1037]: <info>  [1483511681.1918] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK'
Jan  4 08:34:41 XLAP NetworkManager[1037]: <info>  [1483511681.1923] Config: added 'psk' value '<omitted>'
Jan  4 08:34:41 XLAP NetworkManager[1037]: <info>  [1483511681.1929] sup-iface[0x562cd69ef610,wlp3s0b1]: config: set interface ap_scan to 1
Jan  4 08:34:41 XLAP gvfsd-network[4909]: Couldn't create directory monitor on smb://x-gnome-default-workgroup/. Error: The specified location is not mounted
Jan  4 08:34:42 XLAP NetworkManager[1037]: <info>  [1483511682.2093] device (wlp3s0b1): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jan  4 08:34:45 XLAP gvfsd-network[4867]: Couldn't create directory monitor on smb://x-gnome-default-workgroup/. Error: The specified location is not mounted
Jan  4 08:34:49 XLAP gvfsd-network[4919]: Couldn't create directory monitor on smb://x-gnome-default-workgroup/. Error: The specified location is not mounted
Jan  4 08:35:06 XLAP NetworkManager[1037]: <warn>  [1483511706.1142] device (wlp3s0b1): Activation: (wifi) association took too long, failing activation
Jan  4 08:35:06 XLAP NetworkManager[1037]: <info>  [1483511706.1142] device (wlp3s0b1): state change: config -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found') [50 120 53]
Jan  4 08:35:06 XLAP NetworkManager[1037]: <info>  [1483511706.1146] policy: disabling autoconnect for connection 'MIR-Link'.
Jan  4 08:35:06 XLAP NetworkManager[1037]: <warn>  [1483511706.1152] device (wlp3s0b1): Activation: failed for connection 'MIR-Link'
Jan  4 08:35:06 XLAP NetworkManager[1037]: <info>  [1483511706.1160] device (wlp3s0b1): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
Jan  4 08:35:06 XLAP NetworkManager[1037]: <info>  [1483511706.1175] device (wlp3s0b1): supplicant interface state: scanning -> disconnected
```

UPDATE : added solution that solved my issue as an answer

Comment: Hope this Ubuntu [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-troubleshooting-hardware-check.html) would help.

Comment: no it didn't help ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Comment: can any one help ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a driver issue , however that link was useful to know if i use the correct driver or not [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

and after long search I found someone in old release with similar issue speaking about the GUI is the reason . so i installed the XUbuntu and found it working and after that i reinstalled the ubuntu-desktop and that solved the issue .